# Product of two non-negative polynomials has coefficients 0, 1, or 2

Tags: polynomials, factoring, ternary-expansion

A 0-1-2 polynomial is a univariate polynomial where all coefficients are either $0$, $1$, or $2$.
Is it true that if two real polynomials $P(x), Q(x)$, have their product equal to a 0-1-2 polynomial (e.g., $1+x+x^5+ 2 x^{42}$), *and their coefficients are assumed to be non-negative*, and are both monic, then their coefficients are also 0's, 1's and 2's ?

The special case with no $2's$ is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325163/the-coefficients-of-a-product-of-monic-polynomials-are-0-and-1-if-the-polyn).  The question here is a generalization of that question, where coefficients are 0, 1, or 2, instead of 0 or 1.

Comment: @D.W. happy ? In the title would make the title too long, so I did it in the question.

Comment: Thank you, that looks good to me.  The title was already arguably a bit too long as it is -- I think it's better if title is a short summary, rather than a multi-line statement of the problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? This seems so obviously false that simply factoring a few random 0-1-2 polynomials should quickly yield a counterexample.

Comment: @Servaes To be fair, the linked question for 0-1 polynomials also seems obviously false, but the evidence is in favor of it being true...

Comment: @Servaes I tried working in base 3 or 9 or mod 3 or mod 9.  But without succes.

Comment: @mick How does it even make sense to use modular arithmetic? You are asking about polynomials with *real* coefficients.

Comment: OP changed the statement into integer coefficients (after it was answered...). In the current form, I am not sure why is this problem presented as a generalization of the linked post, there $P$ and $Q$ were allowed to be non-integral real numbers.

Comment: My apologies to everyone. I got confused by my own post. So I did a rollback to revision 3. And thereby I accept the answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conjecture is false. Counterexample:

$$ x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+a)(x^2+bx+c)$$
with $a \approx 0.5698$, $b \approx 0.4302$, $c\approx 1.755$.

Comment: @mick The question is trivial if you assume that the factors have non-negative integer coefficients.

Comment: You don't have  $LHS=RHS$ but also an approximation: **your product is not a $0-1-2$ polynomial**

Comment: @mick I see. I think then perhaps you misread the linked problem that you say your problem is a generalization of (as I did at first). For that problem, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are real polynomials (coefficients in $\Bbb{R}$), which is what makes it such a tricky problem.

Comment: @Piquito I suppose I should have been more precise: $-a$ is the unique real root of $x^3+x^2+2x+1$, and the quadratic factor is what you get after dividing the polynomial by $x+a$ (namely, $b=1-a$ and $c = 1/a$.)

Comment: My apologies to everyone. I got confused by my own post. So I did a rollback to revision 3. And thereby I accept this answer !

Comment: @BenjaminWright: I understand now your answer so I put an upvote  (my proof was correct for a coefficient of $P(x)$ greater than $2$ but it remained consider coefficients in $(0,2)$ distinct of $1$ which cannot be decimal with a finite number of digits, because this would give non-monic polynomials. Your counterexample is actually  with irrational numbers in which case it is valid the approximation you give. Regards.

Comment: @mick. Your problem is true if you work in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Comment: @Piquito maybe add a new answer ?

Comment: @mick: You have a partial proof for $P(X)$ having a coefficient greater than $2$ so it remains a proof for $P(x)$ having at least a coefficient greater than $0$ and least than $2$ and distinct of $1$. Your condition of monic polynomials leads to consideration only of irrational for this coefficient so if you restraint to polynomials with rational coefficients your idea is true. For irrational you have counterexamples as  Benjamin Wright has shown. (Sorry for bad English).